# How to style the menu button in BotFramework?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to add menu buttons exactly as shown in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), 
[image]
<sub>(source: [botframework.com](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/images/connector/salon_bot_example.png))</sub>

I tried using HeroCard as below

```
 var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
            .attachments([
                new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title("Main Menu")
                    .subtitle("How can we assist you today?")
                    .text("Please click on a button.")
                    .buttons([
                                builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session,"flight",'','Book a Flight'),
                                builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session,"hotel",'','Book a Hotel'),
                                builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session,"car",'','Book a Car')
                            ])
            ]);
```

I know above is not enough, trying to figure what needs to be done to get the buttons displayed nicely as in the BOT Framework overview page.

Here's how the above code would display. 
[image: My Menu Buttons]

Any assistance would be very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the buttons are being rendered will depend on the channel where you are using your bot. You cannot change the buttons style with the exception of the [WebChat channel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), that is open source and you might be able to tweak the [stylesheets](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/src/scss).

In your image, you are using the emulator, and that's the way button looks like there.

Check the [Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Teams?f=HeroCard&e=example1) to get an idea about how each of channels will render each of the supported features.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm planning to use the BOT in Teams channel. So an alternate approach I'm considering is to get the buttons displayed in a single row. Is that possible? What other attachment should I use other than HeroCard to get the buttons displayed in a row? In my sample above, 'Book a Car' button jumped to the second row.

Comment: I believe that in Teams buttons will be displayed in separate rows. Take a look to the [Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Teams?f=HeroCard&e=example1) to understand more about how each channels render the different features

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel for all the responses. Channel Inspector will be very useful.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Please mark the question as answered

Comment: For Teams | Buttons, it's displaying the buttons nicely in the Inspector. Will the rendering in Teams desktop App be any different? (I still need to try that part ..)

Comment: I'm not sure; I leave that part to you :)

Comment: I just tried it from Teams desktop App and it's displaying the buttons nicely in a single row. :) I had to simplify the button labels to squeeze in few more buttons in a row. I've the screenshot ready to share it here, but I don't see an option to upload it from within the comments.